# How to create chat message block like WhatsApp in android?

Tags: android, layout, textview, whatsapp

I am trying to create a chat layout like WhatsApp. I created block message item layout with message and time. Max width of this block must be 80% of screen. If message textView less of block width then message textView and time textView must be in a line. If message textView more than block width then it must go to another line and end of this line must be time textView. But I am losing timeView. What I must to do?
This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="right|top">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" android:background="#eee" android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:id="@+id/messageView" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10:52"
                android:id="@+id/timeView" android:textColor="#999" android:textSize="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you got the solution? I'm tired looking solution for  this.

Comment: Check the link it will must help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30439423/3278589

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="right|top">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" android:background="#eee" android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:id="@+id/messageView" android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10:52"
                android:id="@+id/timeView" android:textColor="#999" android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It cant help. Because when messageView more than 1 line, up side of timeView will be empty....